# Using Docker container as a Ruby on Rails development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I want to use Docker as a development environment. I am familiar with the basic Docker concepts such as containers, images, volumes, etc. I am also reading [this](https://blog.codeship.com/running-rails-development-environment-docker/) article.

1. I think that there are already images specifically created for RoR development. Could someone recommend me a couple of images to start with?
2. Suppose that I create a container, mount my
   working folder (RoR projects). Besides code writing, there are also command line jobs such as Linux tasks (`update`, `install`), Rails specific commands (Rake, migrations....). I may need to install new binaries or new gems, change Ruby version using `rbenv`. **How can I accomplish these tasks under Docker?** May I type a command in a console or ssh the container?

I managed to create an ubuntu container and run it as following:

```
docker run -it -v /Users/me/Documents/Projects:/var/source_files ubuntu
```

It creates a console for my container. Next I guess I can run commands like `gem install`, `apt-get update` and etc. Is this how we should configure our environment?

I cannot find information on how to run, how to maintain, how add/remove gems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you and what you're comfortable the most with. I'm assuming solo development on some kind of libraries rather than full-fledged apps[1].

I, for example, tend to use [Makefiles when developing on specific Golang projects](https://github.com/odino/docsql/blob/master/Makefile) and have some separate images I tend to use for different occasions. For example, if I have to test a Python / Node scripts, I simply type `play` and I get into a silly container with a few dependencies pre-installed:

- https://github.com/odino/dev#play
- https://github.com/odino/dev/blob/master/play/Dockerfile

In my personal experience, though, I found that shell scripts / aliases work very well across projects, so I tend to have simple aliases that work on most projects. If I were you, for example, I would use a minimalistic approach and alias `dev` to `docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/src $RUBY_IMAGE` so that you can then run `dev rake test`, `dev rails server` etc etc from any project. Your `$RUBY_IMAGE` should have a few utilities installed (htop, curl and so on) and you should be good to go.

Again, I must stress on the fact that it really depends what you're comfortable with -- most of the times I'm extremely productive with just a Makefile.

[1] if working on full-fledged apps [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) works well for a lot of people and has a very good DX. [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) is a tool I'd recommend you to pick up only if you know how to work with kubernetes. We used docker-compose for a long time but have switched to minikube since a few months as it closely mirrors our production environment, and minikube works better (imho) when you have quite a few services talking to each other.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Let me describe a simple scenario. Suppose I created a `Dockerfile` with all necessary tools/gems and share the image with my team members. Later I or one of the members spots that some gem or binary is missing or need to be installed for some other work. How do we proceed? How can I fix it? Do I have to install it manually from the command line from the container? Or should I add it to the Dockerfile and ... update the container? If so how do we update?

Comment: Next, I guess I will have to notify all team members to update their containers too, so that the project won't crash when they run it on their container. In this case I see no advantage of using Docker if team members may install different versions of gems/binaries that may result in different behaviour of the application we are working on.

Comment: If you are working within a team I would *strongly* suggest minikube (a bit more complicated to start with) or docker-compose (probably what you want to look at).

With both you simply define a Dockerfile for each and every project, build the image and run it. When the Dockerfile changes (you add a new library) you will have to tell people to update their image (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1487).

Start with docker-compose for now -- very user-friendly and solves most of your problems.

Comment: Also, you should really understand whether you want to use docker as a development environment only or to run the software in production, because the images you will build in these cases are going to be very, very different from each other.

With our team, for example, the docker images we use in dev are the same we deploy on live, so no htop, no netstat...